# How do I use ternary operator in generic repository function?

Tags: c#, jquery, grid, linq-to-entities, gijgo-treeview

I am doing an MVC4 project using Gijgo grid. I want a single generic repository function to work for all grids in the project. So, I have converted the server side code in Gijgo website to get data, filter and sort data into a generic function. Since in Gijgo grid's server-side code, all functionality of parameters passed from jquery to server-side code is automatically taken care of. For my customization, I need to use a ternary operator to check if the filter parameter is empty (then return all data) & if not empty, then return filtered data.

I have a service layer which service classes and a function Get for each service - which calls the generic repository function"Get" for that service module. For a module, the service class has a function "Get" which calls the repository "Get" function to get data for the grid.

Here are the explanations:

I have ProductService in my ServiceLayer which has a function "Get" to call the generic repository "Get" function.

```
                            public IEnumerable<ProductDTO> Get(string product, string subCategory, string description,int? page = null, int? pageSize = null, string sortBy = null, bool isDescending = false)
        {


            var products = _unitOfWork.ProductRepository
               .Get(
               x => (product != null ? x.EnglishProductName.Contains(product.Trim()) : false) ||
               (subCategory != null ? x.DimProductSubcategory.EnglishProductSubcategoryName.Contains(subCategory.Trim()) : false) ||
               (description != null ? x.EnglishDescription.Contains(description.Trim()) : false),
               sortBy,
                isDescending,
                page,
               pageSize,
               includeProperties: player => player.DimProductSubcategory
               ).AsQueryable();

                if (products.Any())
                {
                 return products.ToList().Select(Mapper.Map<DimProduct, ProductDTO>);
                }

                return Enumerable.Empty<ProductDTO>();
        }
```

Generic Repository "Get" function below

```
                 public virtual List<TEntity> Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null, string sortBy = null, bool isDescending = false,
                int? page = null,
                int? pageSize = null, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includeProperties)
                    {
                        IQueryable<TEntity> query = DbSet;
                          foreach (Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> include in includeProperties)
                            query = query.Include(include);


                        if (filter != null)
                            query = query.Where(filter);

                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortBy))
                        {
                            query = SortByColumnExt.OrderBy(query, sortBy, isDescending);
                        }

                           HttpContext.Current.Session["Total"] = query.Count();

                        if (page.HasValue && pageSize.HasValue)
                        {
                            int start = (page.Value - 1) * pageSize.Value;
                            var records = query.Skip(start).Take(pageSize.Value).ToList();

                            return (records.ToList());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return (query.ToList());

                        }

                    }
```

My problem is this code section of service function:

```
   var products = _unitOfWork.ProductRepository
               .Get(
               x => (product != null ? x.EnglishProductName.Contains(product.Trim()) : false) ||
               (subCategory != null ? x.DimProductSubcategory.EnglishProductSubcategoryName.Contains(subCategory.Trim()) : false) ||
               (description != null ? x.EnglishDescription.Contains(description.Trim()) : false),
               sortBy,
                isDescending,
                page,
               pageSize,
               includeProperties: player => player.DimProductSubcategory
               ).AsQueryable();
```

I want the ternary operator to return whole data if filter parameters EnglishProductName, EnglishProductSubcategoryName and EnglishDescription are passed as empty

> ""

from jquery, that is when the grid first loads or when user don't enter filter option. This is automatically taken care of in Gijgo grid (in the link I provided above).

Here's the code from Gijgo's Manage Ajax Sourced Data Grid.
***Front End***

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <title>Manage Ajax Sourced Data With Grid</title>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <link href="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.13/css/gijgo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <style>
                .form-row { display: flex; margin-bottom: 29px; }
                .form-row:last-child { margin-bottom: 0px; }
                .margin-top-10 { margin-top: 10px; }
                .float-left { float: left; }
                .float-right { float: right; }
                .display-inline { display: inline; }
                .display-inline-block { display: inline-block; }
                .width-200 { width: 200px; }
                .clear-both { clear: both; }
                .gj-display-none { display: none; }
            </style>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.13/js/gijgo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="margin-top-10">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <form class="display-inline">
                        <input id="txtName" type="text" placeholder="Name..." class="gj-textbox-md display-inline-block width-200" />
                        <input id="txtNationality" type="text" placeholder="Nationality..." class="gj-textbox-md display-inline-block width-200" />
                        <button id="btnSearch" type="button" class="gj-button-md">Search</button>
                        <button id="btnClear" type="button" class="gj-button-md">Clear</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="float-right">
                    <button id="btnAdd" type="button" class="gj-button-md">Add New Record</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear-both"></div>
            <div class="margin-top-10">
                <table id="grid"></table>
            </div>

            <div id="dialog" class="gj-display-none">
                <div data-role="body">
                    <input type="hidden" id="ID" />
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <input type="text" class="gj-textbox-md" id="Name" placeholder="Name...">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <select id="Nationality" width="100%" placeholder="Nationality..."></select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <input type="text" id="DateOfBirth" placeholder="Date Of Birth..." width="100%" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <label for="IsActive"><input type="checkbox" id="IsActive" /> &nbsp;Is Active?</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div data-role="footer">
                    <button type="button" id="btnSave" class="gj-button-md">Save</button>
                    <button type="button" id="btnCancel" class="gj-button-md">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                var grid, dialog, nationalityDropdown, dateOfBirth, isActiveCheckbox;
                function Edit(e) {
                    $('#ID').val(e.data.id);
                    $('#Name').val(e.data.record.Name);
                    nationalityDropdown.value(e.data.record.CountryID);
                    dateOfBirth.value(e.data.record.DateOfBirth);
                    isActiveCheckbox.state(e.data.record.IsActive ? 'checked' : 'unchecked');
                    dialog.open('Edit Player');
                }
                function Save() {
                    var record = {
                        ID: $('#ID').val(),
                        Name: $('#Name').val(),
                        CountryID: nationalityDropdown.value(),
                        DateOfBirth: gj.core.parseDate(dateOfBirth.value(), 'mm/dd/yyyy').toISOString(),
                        IsActive: $('#IsActive').prop('checked')
                    };
                    $.ajax({ url: '/Players/Save', data: { record: record }, method: 'POST' })
                        .done(function () {
                            dialog.close();
                            grid.reload();
                        })
                        .fail(function () {
                            alert('Failed to save.');
                            dialog.close();
                        });
                }
                function Delete(e) {
                    if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
                        $.ajax({ url: '/Players/Delete', data: { id: e.data.id }, method: 'POST' })
                            .done(function () {
                                grid.reload();
                            })
                            .fail(function () {
                                alert('Failed to delete.');
                            });
                    }
                }
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    grid = $('#grid').grid({
                        primaryKey: 'ID',
                        dataSource: '/Players/Get',
                        columns: [
                            { field: 'ID', width: 56 },
                            { field: 'Name', sortable: true },
                            { field: 'CountryName', title: 'Nationality', sortable: true },
                            { field: 'DateOfBirth', sortable: true, type: 'date' },
                            { field: 'IsActive', title: 'Active?', type: 'checkbox', width: 90, align: 'center' },
                            { width: 64, tmpl: '<span class="material-icons gj-cursor-pointer">edit</span>', align: 'center', events: { 'click': Edit } },
                            { width: 64, tmpl: '<span class="material-icons gj-cursor-pointer">delete</span>', align: 'center', events: { 'click': Delete } }
                        ],
                        pager: { limit: 5 }
                    });
                    dialog = $('#dialog').dialog({
                        autoOpen: false,
                        resizable: false,
                        modal: true,
                        width: 360
                    });
                    nationalityDropdown = $('#Nationality').dropdown({ dataSource: '/Locations/GetCountries', valueField: 'id' });
                    dateOfBirth = $('#DateOfBirth').datepicker();
                    isActiveCheckbox = $('#IsActive').checkbox();
                    $('#btnAdd').on('click', function () {
                        $('#ID').val('');
                        $('#Name').val('');
                        nationalityDropdown.value('');
                        dateOfBirth.value('');
                        isActiveCheckbox.state('unchecked');
                        dialog.open('Add Player');
                    });
                    $('#btnSave').on('click', Save);
                    $('#btnCancel').on('click', function () {
                        dialog.close();
                    });
                    $('#btnSearch').on('click', function () {
                        grid.reload({ page: 1, name: $('#txtName').val(), nationality: $('#txtNationality').val() });
                    });
                    $('#btnClear').on('click', function () {
                        $('#txtName').val('');
                        $('#txtNationality').val('');
                        grid.reload({ name: '', nationality: '' });
                    });
                });
            </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

***Backed-Code***

```
            using Gijgo.Asp.NET.Examples.Models.Entities;
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Web.Mvc;

        namespace Gijgo.Asp.NET.Examples.Controllers
        {
            public class PlayersController : Controller
            {
                public JsonResult Get(int? page, int? limit, string sortBy, string direction, string name, string nationality, string placeOfBirth)
                {
                    List<Models.DTO.Player> records;
                    int total;
                    using (ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext())
                    {
                        var query = context.Players.Select(p => new Models.DTO.Player
                        {
                            ID = p.ID,
                            Name = p.Name,
                            PlaceOfBirth = p.PlaceOfBirth,
                            DateOfBirth = p.DateOfBirth,
                            CountryID = p.CountryID,
                            CountryName = p.Country != null ? p.Country.Name : "",
                            IsActive = p.IsActive,
                            OrderNumber = p.OrderNumber
                        });

                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
                        {
                            query = query.Where(q => q.Name.Contains(name));
                        }

                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(nationality))
                        {
                            query = query.Where(q => q.CountryName != null && q.CountryName.Contains(nationality));
                        }

                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(placeOfBirth))
                        {
                            query = query.Where(q => q.PlaceOfBirth != null && q.PlaceOfBirth.Contains(placeOfBirth));
                        }

                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortBy) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(direction))
                        {
                            if (direction.Trim().ToLower() == "asc")
                            {
                                switch (sortBy.Trim().ToLower())
                                {
                                    case "name":
                                        query = query.OrderBy(q => q.Name);
                                        break;
                                    case "countryname":
                                        query = query.OrderBy(q => q.CountryName);
                                        break;
                                    case "placeOfBirth":
                                        query = query.OrderBy(q => q.PlaceOfBirth);
                                        break;
                                    case "dateofbirth":
                                        query = query.OrderBy(q => q.DateOfBirth);
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                switch (sortBy.Trim().ToLower())
                                {
                                    case "name":
                                        query = query.OrderByDescending(q => q.Name);
                                        break;
                                    case "countryname":
                                        query = query.OrderByDescending(q => q.CountryName);
                                        break;
                                    case "placeOfBirth":
                                        query = query.OrderByDescending(q => q.PlaceOfBirth);
                                        break;
                                    case "dateofbirth":
                                        query = query.OrderByDescending(q => q.DateOfBirth);
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            query = query.OrderBy(q => q.OrderNumber);
                        }

                        total = query.Count();
                        if (page.HasValue && limit.HasValue)
                        {
                            int start = (page.Value - 1) * limit.Value;
                            records = query.Skip(start).Take(limit.Value).ToList();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            records = query.ToList();
                        }
                    }

                    return this.Json(new { records, total }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }

                [HttpPost]
                public JsonResult Save(Models.DTO.Player record)
                {
                    Player entity;
                    using (ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext())
                    {
                        if (record.ID > 0)
                        {
                            entity = context.Players.First(p => p.ID == record.ID);
                            entity.Name = record.Name;
                            entity.PlaceOfBirth = record.PlaceOfBirth;
                            entity.DateOfBirth = record.DateOfBirth;
                            entity.CountryID = record.CountryID;
                            entity.Country = context.Locations.FirstOrDefault(l => l.ID == record.CountryID);
                            entity.IsActive = record.IsActive;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            context.Players.Add(new Player
                            {
                                Name = record.Name,
                                PlaceOfBirth = record.PlaceOfBirth,
                                DateOfBirth = record.DateOfBirth,
                                CountryID = record.CountryID,
                                Country = context.Locations.FirstOrDefault(l => l.ID == record.CountryID),
                                IsActive = record.IsActive
                            });
                        }
                        context.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    return Json(new { result = true });
                }

                [HttpPost]
                public JsonResult Delete(int id)
                {
                    using (ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext())
                    {
                        Player entity = context.Players.First(p => p.ID == id);
                        context.Players.Remove(entity);
                        context.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    return Json(new { result = true });
                }

                public JsonResult GetTeams(int playerId, int? page, int? limit)
                {
                    List<Models.DTO.PlayerTeam> records;
                    int total;
                    using (ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext())
                    {
                        var query = context.PlayerTeams.Where(pt => pt.PlayerID == playerId).Select(pt => new Models.DTO.PlayerTeam
                        {
                            ID = pt.ID,
                            PlayerID = pt.PlayerID,
                            FromYear = pt.FromYear,
                            ToYear = pt.ToYear,
                            Team = pt.Team,
                            Apps = pt.Apps,
                            Goals = pt.Goals
                        });

                        total = query.Count();
                        if (page.HasValue && limit.HasValue)
                        {
                            int start = (page.Value - 1) * limit.Value;
                            records = query.OrderBy(pt => pt.FromYear).Skip(start).Take(limit.Value).ToList();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            records = query.ToList();
                        }
                    }

                    return this.Json(new { records, total }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please format your code, its unreadable

Comment: Just posted entire thing

Comment: *"Just posted entire thing"* ....why??  That's not a [mcve] . Problems should be scaled down to reflect only the immediate problem....not a complete project dump

Comment: @charlietfl I will add the view part & jquery part later on(if space limit on StackOverflow permits) but the problem is when I pass the filter parameters as " ", it returns nothing cuz of the ternary operator in the Get(). I just wanted to make the ternary option to either return full data or filtered data(using contains). I checked it in Linqpad, the problem lies there. I just don't know how to fix that in the best possible way.